# Is there an automatic way to determine the netmask from a site-local address?

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

In Android (or Java, I suppose), it's easy enough to determine whether a given address is site-local:

```
InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName (addr_string);
if (a.isSiteLocalAddress())
    ...
```

However, each of the three flavors of site-local addresses has a different netmask associated with it.  Is there a quick and easy to generate the netmask from the address??

Comment: There are ultimately more than three possibilities for a netmask, though its true that ones which are assigned by whole octet are most common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netmask is used to establish which part of an addres is the network address, which part is dedicated to the hosts and which one is broadcast.

You make a bit-by-bit and between ip address and subnet mask in order to individuate each part.

You need more information than ip address in order to get netmask.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect you accidentally a word, but thanks for the assist.